# Best practice for avoiding mutating parameters?

Tags: ruby

Can someone suggest a good, ruby-idiomatic, way of avoiding this?

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
end

a = {one: 1}
x = Foo.new; x.bar = a

x.bar[:two] = 2
p a  #=> {one: 1, two: 2}
```

- I could simply not allow the users of a class to access its attributes, which solves the problem...in this case. (What about passing parameters to a method?) Anyway, avoiding everything but `attr_reader`, and using that only on non-mutable attributes, doesn't seem very Ruby-ish.
- Or, I can just not write any code which mutates values, which appeals, but is not exactly easy to do in Ruby.
- I could systematically `dup` or `clone` every parameter my class is given -- except that those methods don't work on Nilclass, Fixnums, Symbols, etc -- and worse, `responds_to?(:dup) == true` for those types. (Also, neither `dup` nor `clone` do a deep copy.)

In the example above I modify the `bar` attribute in the caller, but the problem remains the same if the code is in the class, or if I use a method on the class instead of `attr_accessor` : If I want a class which can accept a value and do something with it, and if for some reason I have to do that by mutating that value somewhere -- is there an idiomatic way in ruby to ensure that I don't infect the caller with that mutated value?

In Ruby we are supposed not to care about the type of the incoming data very much, but it looks as if I have to care about it quite a lot in order to tell how to make this value I want to mutate safe. If it's a NullObject or a Fixnum or a Symbol it's fine, otherwise I can `dup` it ... unless I need to deep copy it.

That can't be right, can it?

---

#### Edit: After Some More Thought

Sergio is of course right -- sometimes you *want* this behaviour. Not because using the side effect in your code is a good idea, but because sometimes the class you are passing a message to needs a live reference to an object that might change afterwards.

The only time this behaviour is going to be problematic is when you are passing an Enumerable. If I pass an Array or a Hash, I really don't want the receiver to modify that. So my takeaway is:

- Do what Sergio said and code defensively whenever I pass stuff to a receiver, just in case the person who coded it hasn't been careful.
- Implement a blanket rule in my own classes: dup all incoming Enumerables.

Comment: What is the objective you're trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev -- I want to avoid writing classes that mutate the parameters they are given because that will cause bugs and unexpected behavior in the caller...

Comment: It seems to me that it is as simple as not writing code that mutates parameters. You can kinda enforce this by using more primitive types and, in case of strings, arrays and friends, not using their bang methods.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev -- as I hope I demonstrated above, that's not as easy as it sounds.  An empty class with `attr_accessor` mutates parameters!

Comment: Depends on what you call "parameters". I see no methods with arguments there (I thought you're talking about this). Also, the class doesn't mutate anything. The calling code does. So just don't do that :)

Comment: Okay, let me flesh out the question a little.

Comment: Also this might be useful: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ow0lr63y4Mw

Comment: How about [freezing](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-freeze) the object you don't want to be modified?

Comment: @zwippie -- I do want to modify it, though. I just don't want to infect the caller with that change.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. What do you mean by "modify the `one` attribute in the caller"? Where is the `one` attribute? What is a caller?

Comment: @zwippie -- sorry, should be `bar` not `one`.  Edited.  The caller is the thing that calls the method on the class...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is responsibility of the caller to shield itself from code being called. Let's say, you have some command line options parsing code. You got this hash of parameters and you want to do some validation (or something). Now, the validating code was written by some other guy who likes to do things in-place for "efficiency". So it is likely that your hash will be mutated and you won't be able to use it later.

Solution? Pass a *copy*.

```
validate_params! Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(params)) # deep copy
```

Note that in some cases mutation is *desirable*. So it must be the caller who controls the effect (allows or prevents it).

Comment: Good idea to use `Marshal` to deep copy. I've never seen that done.

Comment: Given that the problematic behaviour is exhibited by core helpers like `attr_accessor`, it seems as if this is the **only** way to solve the problem idiomatically...

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using `freeze`:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar

  def bar=(value)
    @bar = value.freeze # You may need to freeze nested values too
  end
end

a = { one: 1 }
x = Foo.new
x.bar = a

x.bar[:two] = 2
# raises: can't modify frozen Hash
```

Or if you prefer to not change `Foo`, freeze the value when assigning:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
end

a = {one: 1}
x = Foo.new
x.bar = a.freeze

x.bar[:two] = 2
# raises: can't modify frozen Hash
```

Comment: So by using freeze, we've successfully stopped the example from working.  How do I get the same functionality as the example, without the unpleasant side effects I've described?  (If it helps, imagine a method on Foo which modifies the bar attribute. I want that.  I don't want a to change.)